# What is the Javadoc?

Tags: javadoc

In past paper questions, it states to define a bunch of terms in the context of Java. The term 'Javadoc' is included in the list. I went through every lecture and the term never came up and most info online is quite technical.

What, in the most easily digestable terms, is the Javadoc?

My current (and likely incorrect) understanding of the Javadoc:

the predefined classes etc used in the Java Development Environment, in HTML format (ie published online - the online part especially sounds incorrect to me)

I used the following sources to try find the definition, but it still isn't entirely clear to me.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc

Comment: Have you tried to read linked articles?

Comment: yes I have. They just don't make sense to me. "Generates HTML pages of API documentation from Java source files" means nothing to me. Hence why I ask for a more simplistic breakdown.

Comment: please play with http://www.docjar.net/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html and click between `javadoc` and `source`, as @Sharon182 mentioned - it generates documentation, something that you can read without looking into source Java code

Comment: thanks for that. The definitions meant nothing until I was able to actually see it. Now 'generates...from source files' makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a tool that comes with the JDK and used to generate documentation for java code files in HTML format.